# How do I group logs in Kibana/Logstash?

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

We have an ELK setup and the Logstash is receiving all the logs from the Filebeat installed on the server. So when I open Kibana and it asks for an index I put just a `*` for the index value and go to the Discover tab to check the logs and it shows each line of the log in a separate expandable section.

I want to be able to group the logs based on the timestamp first and then on a common ID that is generated in our logs per request to identify it from the rest. An example of the logs we get :

```
DEBUG [2018-11-23 11:28:22,847][298b364850d8] Some information
INFO  [2018-11-23 11:27:33,152][298b364850d8] Some information
INFO  [2018-11-24 11:31:20,407][b66a88287eeb] Some information
DEBUG [2018-11-23 11:31:20,407][b66a88287eeb] Some information
```

I would like to see all logs for request ID : 298b364850d8 in the same drop down given they are continuous logs. Then it can break into the second dropdown again grouped by the request ID : b66a88287eeb in the order of timestamp.

Is this even possible or am I expecting too much from the tool?

OR if there is a better strategy to grouping of logs I'm more than happy to listen to suggestions.

I have been told by a friend that I could configure this in logstash to group logs based on some regex n stuff but I just don't know where and how to configure it to fo the grouping.

I am completely new to the whole ELK stack to bear with my questions which might be quite elementary in nature.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is truly a little vague and broad as you say. However, I will try to help :)

1. Check the index that you define in the [logstash output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-index). This is the index that need to be defined Kibana - not *.
2. [Create an Index Pattern to Connect to Elasticsearch](https://orchestrator.uipath.com/docs/creating-an-index-pattern-to-connect-to-elasticsearch). This will parse the fields of the logs and will allow you to filter as you want.
3. It recommend using a GUI tool (like [Cerebro](http://www.atechref.com/blog/elk-stack/elk-stack-monitor-elastic-nodes/)) to better understand what is going on in you ES. It would also help you to get better clue of the indices you have there.

Good Luck

Comment: thanks a lot for sharing those links. Let me check them out. I understand my request is vague at best coz I have used Splunk before in my previous company but otherwise it's just been tail-ing the logs. And I've never done the dev-ops bit of it. I was told that an ELK setup would provide me with a good UI to search for logs and setup alerts etc. Hence the vagueness of the requirement as I am still figuring out how best to use this tool and set it up so we can program it to our advantage. Sorry about that :)

Comment: Sure, No problem I totally understand that. Just mentioned that so you know that my answer is quite general and maybe not exactly what you needed.

Comment: sorry I haven't had time to spend on this. But the 2nd link you shared is something I already tried earlier but haven't experimented extensively with it yet. Cerebro seems pretty interesting to me with the index pattern and analysis tool. I will give that a shot. And I'll go through the first link since that is the official documentation. I hope to do this over the weekend and respond back by then. Thanks for your help and guidance and on checking back :) Really appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

You can use @timeStamp filter and search query  as below sample image to filter what you want. 
[image]